# Setting Property when No DataTrigger Values are Satisfied WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styles, datatrigger

I am VERY new to WPF AND C#, so there may be a much better way to accomplish what I am attempting. Therefore, I am open to other methods.

As far as what I've got, I am trying to program a Digital VMB (Visual Management Board) for the maintenance department where I work. They want a section to display the number of days our plant has gone without an accident: "Days Safe". I successfully have the binding set for this TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DaysSafe}" FontSize="60"  FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
```

I have a series of DataTriggers to change the Foreground color of the text to a certain color, based on the value of the text. Basically, I want the DaysSafe text to be:
Red when 0
Orange when 1 and so on (you can see the colors in my code below):

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DaysSafe}" FontSize="60"  FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Style.Triggers >
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="OrangeRed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="4">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="5">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GreenYellow" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

This functions correctly, the colors change when the days are lower. HOWEVER, I would like for the foreground color to "Default" to green when the value of DaysSafe is over 5. Right now, any value above 5 is black when I want it to be green. I tried adding the foreground="green" attribute in the first TextBlock section, but this overrides the DataTriggers and the foreground is always green.

Any help with how I may create a default value for the foreground?
Thanks.

Comment: Just add `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />` to the Style itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just add a setter that sets the default Foreground of the TextBlock to Green:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
    <Style.Triggers >
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="OrangeRed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="3">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="4">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DaysSafe}" Value="5">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GreenYellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Such a simple fix yet I couldn't seem to find anything out there that covered this. Up-voted but since I'm a noob I guess it won't show up until I'm over 15 rep. Have a good day!